# Is it possible to create a very permissive grammar using Menhir?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, peg, menhir

I'm trying to parse some bits and pieces of Verilog - I'm primarily interested in extracting module definitions and instantiations.

In verilog a module is defined like:

```
module foo ( ... ) endmodule;
```

And a module is instantiated in one of two different possible ways:

```
foo fooinst ( ... );
foo #( ...list of params... ) fooinst ( .... );
```

At this point I'm only interested in finding the name of the defined or instantiated module; 'foo' in both cases above.

Given this menhir grammar (verParser.mly):

```
%{ 

  type expr =   Module of expr 
           | ModInst of expr
           | Ident of string 
           | Int of int
           | Lparen 
           | Rparen  
           | Junk 
           | ExprList of expr list

%}

%token <string> INT
%token <string> IDENT
%token  LPAREN RPAREN MODULE TICK OTHER HASH EOF



%start expr2
%type <expr> mod_expr
%type <expr> expr1
%type <expr list> expr2

%%


mod_expr:
  | MODULE IDENT LPAREN    { Module ( Ident $2) }
  | IDENT IDENT LPAREN     { ModInst ( Ident $1) }
  | IDENT HASH  LPAREN     { ModInst ( Ident $1) };

junk: 
  |  LPAREN {  }
  |  RPAREN {  }
  |  HASH { } 
  |  INT {  };

expr1:
  | junk* mod_expr junk* { $2 } ;

expr2: 
  | expr1* EOF { $1 };
```

When I try this out in the menhir interpretter it works fine extracting the module instantion:

```
MODULE IDENT LPAREN
ACCEPT
[expr2:
  [list(expr1):
    [expr1:
      [list(junk):]
      [mod_expr: MODULE IDENT LPAREN]
      [list(junk):]
    ]
    [list(expr1):]
  ]
  EOF
]
```

It works fine for the single module instantiation:

```
IDENT IDENT LPAREN
ACCEPT
[expr2:
  [list(expr1):
    [expr1:
      [list(junk):]
      [mod_expr: IDENT IDENT LPAREN]
      [list(junk):]
    ]
    [list(expr1):]
  ]
  EOF
]
```

But of course, if there is an IDENT that appears prior to any of these it will REJECT:

```
IDENT MODULE IDENT LPAREN IDENT IDENT LPAREN
REJECT
```

... and of course there will be identifiers in an actual verilog file prior to these defs.

I'm trying not to have to fully specify a Verilog grammar, instead I want to build the grammar up slowly and incrementally to eventually parse more and more of the language.

If I add IDENT to the junk rule, that fixes the problem above, but then the module instantiation rule doesn't work because now the junk rule is capturing the IDENT.

Is it possible to create a very permissive rule that will bypass stuff I don't want to match, or is it generally required that you must create a complete grammar to actually do something like this?

Is it possible to create a rule that would let me match:

```
MODULE IDENT LPAREN stuff* RPAREN ENDMODULE
```

where "stuff*" initially matches everything but RPAREN?

Something like :

```
stuff: 
  | !RPAREN { } ;
```

I've used PEG parsers in the past which would allow constructs like that.

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason why Verilog-Perl or an ANTLR verilog grammar is not suitable?

Comment: @Adam12: ANTLR involves Java. Verilog-Perl may work, but I think we'll need something a bit faster than Perl (many thousands of Verilog files to process).  May end up going with C++ and Boost::spirit since PEG parsers can be setup to more easily parse with an incomplete grammar.

Comment: If you think PEG are better suited for the job (I have no experience of using LR grammars for partial/fuzzy parsing), you may be interested in [Aurochs](https://github.com/berke/aurochs), a PEG parser generator in OCaml land.

Comment: It is true most of the docs are Java-centric but there is a C target and C++ target for ANTLR. Although the C target has some memory consumption issues, my own tests with a 1364-2005 grammar showed about 40 times the performance of the Java target.

Comment: @gasche: Thanks, I have used aurochs in the past, however I'm not sure it will be fast enough for my needs (thousands of files to look through) - also not entirely sure how to call from inside of OCaml. I took a look at peg/leg and was able to create a PEG grammar with it that seems to work (it generates a C parser so it should be very fast).

Answer (score 1):

I've decided that PEG is a better fit for a permissive, non-exhaustive grammar.  Took a look at [peg/leg](http://piumarta.com/software/peg/) and was able to very quickly put together a leg grammar that does what I need to do:

```
start   = ( comment | mod_match | char)

line    = < (( '\n' '\r'* ) | ( '\r' '\n'* )) > { lines++;  chars += yyleng; }
module_decl =    module  modnm:ident lparen ( !rparen . )* rparen   {  chars += yyleng; printf("Module    decl: <%s>\n",yytext);}
module_inst = modinstname:ident ident lparen { chars += yyleng; printf("Module Inst: <%s>\n",yytext);}
         |modinstname:ident hash lparen { chars += yyleng; printf("Module Inst: <%s>\n",yytext);} 

mod_match = ( module_decl | module_inst ) 
module     =  'module' ws                { modules++;    chars +=yyleng; printf("Module: <%s>\n", yytext);  } 
endmodule  = 'endmodule' ws              { endmodules++; chars +=yyleng; printf("EndModule: <%s>\n", yytext); } 

kwd = (module|endmodule)
ident   = !kwd<[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+>-    { words++;  chars += yyleng;  printf("Ident: <%s>\n", yytext);  }

char    = .                 { chars++; }
lparen  =  '(' - 
rparen  =  ')' - 
hash    =  '#' 

- =  ( space | comment )*
ws = space+
space = ' ' | '\t' | EOL
comment = '//' ( !EOL .)* EOL
          | '/*' ( !'*/' .)* '*/' 
EOF = !.
EOL = '\r\n' | '\n' | '\r'
```

[Aurochs](https://github.com/berke/aurochs) is possibly also an option, but I have concerns about speed and memory usage of an Aurochs generated parser.  peg/leg produce a parser in C which should be quite speedy.